# Renaming Property Within Array in MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb

I am wanting to rename a property in one of our MongoDB collections because it was pluralized where it should be singular. However, when I try this in the Mongo shell:

```
db.getCollection("customers").updateMany( { _id: {$exists: true} }, { $rename: { "billingOptions.0.paymentCards": "billingOptions.0.paymentCard" } } )
```

... I get this "cannot be an array element" error:

> "errmsg" : "The source field cannot be an array element,
>   'billingOptions.0.paymentCards' in doc with _id:
>   ObjectId('3d12fefc093r76146ccf50g8') has an array field called
>   'billingOptions'"

Not sure why this would be a problem, since I'm telling it precisely which array element to target. But, either way, this being the case, what operation can I use to rename this property

Here's an example of the relevant section of the document as it is now:

```
"billingOptions" : [
    {
        "method" : "private", 
        "paymentCards": {
            "deleted" : false,
            // other props
        }
    }, 
]
```

And this is what I'd like it to look like after:

```
"billingOptions" : [
    {
        "method" : "private", 
        "paymentCard": {
            "deleted" : false,
            // other props
        }
    }, 
]
```

Note that "billingOptions" is a property on the root of the document. All I want to do is rename all instances of "paymentCards" to "paymentCard", since it is a singular object here, rather than an array.

Comment: Do you want to rename `paymentCards` only from first billingOption (index `0`) or from all of them ? Could you share a sample document and expected updated doc ?

Comment: Ideally, I would do all of them, not just the first array element.

Comment: I added the document structure above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to replace existing collection and [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to replace existing array in each document

```
db.customers.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            billingOptions: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$billingOptions",
                    in: {
                        method: "$$this.method",
                        // other fields
                        paymentCard: "$$this.paymentCards"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "$customers"
    }
])
```

Comment: Ah, okay. And I need to explicitly include all props within a "billingOption" (such as "method"), otherwise those will be wiped out, correct?

Comment: @Muirik yes, that's the easiest way